# How to delete from MongoDB with conditional from another collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections on my MongoDB.
Let say:
accounts, users

I want to delete all the users that was last updated 10 months ago where the account is not active anymore.

Into my users collection I have an accountId attribute, that related to the account.

Is it possible to create a query to delete the users with the requirements? Or what's the best approach for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the $lookup function. You could use it to "join"the tables.
Then you can iterate over the cursor and remove the document (won't perform very well for large collections)

```
var cursor = db.grades.aggregate(pipeline);
cursor.forEach(function (doc){
 db.grades.remove({"_id": doc._id});
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I was reading trying to find other solutions, but the only options are cursors to loop through them one by one and use aggregation and lookup, which will cause me some issues because I can't have more indexes.But it is what it is... hehe Thank your the help! :)

Comment: There's something else you could try that might perform better. 
1-Use aggregation to get all the ids that you need to delete
2-Get the result and run a remove() query